# Han tenido problemas con ParameterizedTypeReference en Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, unittest

Estuve haciendo una prueba unitaria en Spring Boot 3.2.0 con Java 17 y me quedé estancado en un error utilizando **ParameterizedTypeReference**.
Aquí la clase:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class EventoControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void debeRetornarUnEventoPorId() {
        ParameterizedTypeReference<BaseResponse<EventoResponse>> typeReference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {};
        ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<EventoResponse>> response = 
        this.restTemplate.getForEntity("/client/evento/14", typeReference);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

El error indica lo siguiente:

> `Cannot resolve method 'getForEntity(String, ParameterizedTypeReference<BaseResponse<EventoResponse>>)`

Les agradecería darme una luz, quizá estoy haciendo algo mal, de momento decidí cambiar la implementación y no parametrizar EventoResponse, sino recibir un object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final decidí usar String como tipo de respuesta y sigo usando `BaseResponse<EventoResponse>` sin problemas en el controller.
Dejo un ejemplo:)

```
@Test
void debeRetornarUnEventoPorId() {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = this.restTemplate.getForEntity("/client/evento/14", String.class);
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);

    DocumentContext documentContext = JsonPath.parse(response.getBody());
    System.out.println(documentContext.read("$.data.eventoId").toString());
}
```

Sldos:)